# Tilted Dial Rotation

Tags: animation, mesh, objects, armature, transforms

Spinning Faucet Dials are easy in blender when the axes are in default 90 degree space, but I have a faucet with tilted dials and I need to rotate them for animation, but I can't figure out how to rotate them like you would expect them to without them getting all contorted. Can someone please fix my blend file so this works correctly.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/vny3jqc03hbrs5q/Slanted%20Faucet%20Rotation.blend?dl=0

Comment: Could you please strip down your blend file to smaller size? Delete any unnecessary objects and leave only the one from the subject. Also upload it to: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: If I understand the problem well you can parent all dials to any other object that represents the faucet center (or say an empty) and rotate that object instead.

Comment: Blend file already is stripped to just subject just download the file unless your on dial up?

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the movement type for the transform manipulators to "local" instead of  "Global". This changes the movement to correspond to the object's position/rotation. once you have done that and put the menipulator wigit to "rotation" it should be easy to rotate the faucet handles like you want.

[image]